# Menelaus Theorem and Ideal Points

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Q1: Assume that all 3 Menelaus points are proper and that exactly one of them is ideal. Prove their ratio to be -1 iff the three Menelaus points are collinear.

So I realize this will happen because the ideal point is off the triangle and will thus cause (+)(+)(-) and result in a negative ratio. Is there a more formal approach to this proof?

Q2: Secondly I am trying to prove that it is impossible for two Menelaus points to be ideal. I believe this has to do with how two lines either have a distinct intersection or an ideal point where they intersect. If you had two ideal points then you wouldn't appear to have a triangle (I believe).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean that a point is a Menelaus point? What does it mean for a Menelaus point to be proper/ideal?

Comment: What is the ratio of 3 Menelaus points?

Comment: Menelaus points are three points on a triangle that can be collinear. Ideal points or points at infinity are far away points in the extended Euclidean plane. The ratio of three Menelaus points is either 1 or -1 depending on the direction of our point.